# 入力された日本語をカナ変換する方法

Tags: html, typescript

ionicでアプリ開発をしています。

ユーザが入力した、漢字も含む文字列を、カタカナに変換してサーバに保存したいです。

入力した値を即座にカナ変換するjQueryのプラグインautoKana.jsもあります。
しかしこれだと正確なカナが得られません。
例えば、「明日」という漢字だと本来欲しい値は「アシタ」です。
もしユーザが「明るい」と「日」を入力して「るい」を消して「明日」にした場合、「アシタ」というカナ変換された文字列は取得できません。

使用言語はHTML,CSS,typescriptです。

typescriptで、カナ変換した後にデータベースに保存するようにしたいです。
データベースはcloud firebaseを使用しております。

Comment: 漢字を正確に変換するのは、難しい場合がありますが（「明日」は「あす」と読む場合もありますし）、mecab というソフトは十分にやってくれると思います。mecab なら、サーバ側で変換してデータベースに保存するという流れになります。

Comment: mecabですね。ありがとうございます。試してみます。